# How to implement dynamic file permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, openssh, sftp

I have application that creates a "records" of data. Every record has a directory with "attachments". User creates a record (via app web interface), my applications creates attachments directory and user can add many files to attachment directory.

User has mounted all attachments directory via NFS, so he can easily and conveniently add files from own computer.

I need something like dynamic permission control: **Every time linux want to access a file under attachments directory I want linux to ask my application: User xx wants to read/write file yy? allow?**

Only application know what time the record is "active" and attachments can be added, or record is locked..

Now i'm calling chmod() on files, but it is slow for big file trees in attachments. And it is also not atomic.

---

One workaround that I can imagine could be: Use sshfs instead of NFS and patch openssh's sftp-server to ask for permissions for every file (via some socket api, ... ). Is it possible?

**Edit** - seems to be possible: https://gitlab.com/netajo/sftp-permission-api/

Comment: Filesystem permissions are not intended for this job. You probably end up writing another kernel persmission layer. Closest thing I might think of right now is using app like ownCloud and mirror your groups / permissions there using some API to communicate between cloud and your app so you can set permissions in cloud whenever they are changing in your app.

Comment: You don't need `chmod` on files, you only need a `chmod` on the top user directory, to remove the `rwx` flags to group & other. Without the execute flag on a directory (which is the "traverse" right for directories) you cannot access any file/directory under it.

Comment: Ideas: Use a web-interface, get the web-server to do it. Create a fuse file-system (a user mode file-system).